# Remove string from left and right side of date using python and update as new string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
string = "I went to market on October 29,2017I on London"
12-7-2021mma  --->12-7-2021
kk12/7/2021   ---> 12-7-2021
yy12/9/2021kko  ---> 12/9/2021
```

Is there any solution to get "I went to market on October 29,2017 on London" by removing "I" from October 29,2017I

There are much more cases like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as what you are looking for is extracting the date from a sentence in a rigid format (e.g. '12-7-2021'), you can do it using regular expressions:

```
import re

ss = ['12-7-2021mma', 'kk12/7/2021', 'yy12/9/2021kko']

for ss1 in ss:
    ss_date = re.match(r'[^0-9]*(\d\d?[-/]\d\d?[-/]\d{4})[^0-9]*', ss1)


    if ss_date is not None:
        print(ss_date.group(1))
```

You get:

```
12-7-2021
12/7/2021
12/9/2021
```

Comment: Sure, no problem. If you like the answer you can upvote it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `re.sub` and `str.join` with a list comprehension:

```
import re
string = "I went to market on October 29,2017I on London"
print(' '.join([re.sub('[^\d+,/-]+', '', i) or i for i in string.split()]))
```

Output:

```
I went to market on October 29,2017 on London
```

Comment: I have case sentence like this: "FHYSJ j lOctober 20,2017I Initial Evaluation i. Causing him  03-10-2020l"..  But this output is showing :  "FHYSJ j lOctober 20,2017 Initial Evaluation i. Causing him  03102020".. But I have to remove "l" from "lOctober 20,2017" and should not remove "-" from 03-10-2020

Comment: @Ajay SO sorry I edited my answer, if it works it should be worth an upvote :)